# Angular 2 Get width of a div

Tags: angular, typescript

I've looked at numerous posts but none quite do what I want it to do.
I have a table which goes outside the width of the page and for various reasons I need to get it's width.

I used:

```
@ViewChild('tableToMeasure') elementView: ElementRef;
```

And then put #tableToMeasure on the table. However this seems to error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
```

Even though this works on and only on the parent div of the page.

Any ideas? I need to get it's width on both page load and page resize and change another divs width to be the same value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`elementView` won't be set before `ngAfterViewInit` was called.
If you have your code in `ngOnInit` or the constructor, you'll get this error.

Comment: So I have to use it within ngAfterViewInit()?

Comment: So he should *use* `elementView` only after the viw initialized? So, inside `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: Either inside `ngAfterViewInit` or anything that's executed later, for example an event handler for user actions (click, scroll, ...)

Comment: Hmm I tried it on ngAfterViewInit() but still getting same error

Comment: Hard to tell from the single line of code you posted. Please provide more information than I can have another look. Ideally a Plunker that allows to reproduce. (Plunker provides an Angular template to get you started easily)

Comment: Ah it works but you have to see if theres a value first as it fires off a first time without the element actually being ready. if ((this.elementView != null)) {}
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Perhaps your `#tableToMeasure` is within an `*ngIf`, otherwise it will have a value when `ngAfterViewInit` is called.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'selector',
    template: `<button #tableToMeasure>Click me</button>`
})
export class FeatureComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('tableToMeasure') elementView;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.elementView.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm sorry I tried that but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The solution I found was actually fairly easily; it returns undefined because in your HTML file there is nothing defined as 'tableToMeasure'.

Therefore you have to add `#tableToMeasure` to your HTML element.

Example code HTML file:

```
<div #tableToMeasure style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
   <span>Some content!</span
</div>
```

And in your TypeScript file:

```
@ViewChild('tableToMeasure')elementView: ElementRef;
```

Make sure to import ViewChild and ElementRef from `@angular/core`.

Good luck!