# How to get width of (DOM) Element in Angular 4 after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm looking for a solution in Angular 4 to get the width of DOM element without taking any action (click or window resize), just after the page is loaded, but before I start to draw the svg. I've found a similar case in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845822/angular-2-get-width-of-a-div) but it doesn't work for me. I get the same error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

I need to get the width of div container to set veiwbox of svg I'm drawing inside it.

Here is the template:

```
<div id="what-is-the-width" class="svg-chart-container">
    <svg [innerHTML]="svg"></svg>
</div>
```

and TS file with stuff needed in this case:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

export class SvgChartComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('what-is-the-width') elementView: ElementRef;

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.elementView.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this method gets the data from the server and draw the svg
    this.getSVGChartData();
  }
}
```

Does anyone have ideas how to get this working?

Comment: It seems that "-" is not allowed in reference names, just have got `Uncaught Error: Template parse errors`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can't have the size of an element before the page is loaded. In case it's not clear enough, if the page isn't loaded, then your HTML element isn't loaded.

If you want to set the viewbox of your SVG according to a div, you will need to wait for the page to load, then change the viewbox. It's perfectly doable.

The fastest way of doing that is :

```
<div #container>Container's width is {{ container.offsetWidth }}</div>
<svg:svg [width]="container.offsetWidth"></svg>
```

I'll let you deal with the viewBox attribute, since I don't really know what you want to do with it.

You need to add the `svg:` prefix to tell angular it's not a custom directive, by the way.

Comment: Too simple! :) Thanks, it works! I'll edit the title and question because it is truly unclear. I've meant of course getting the width after the page load but before I fire method drawing the svg.

Comment: No problem ! Remember to mark your issue as resolved too !

Comment: Oh, one more thing. How to pass this value from template to ts file? I need to use it in one more place.

Comment: `@ViewChild('container') container : ElementRef;` is the declaration. To get the value, it's `this.container.nativeElement.offsetWidth`. For your ide, you can use `(this.container.nativeElement as HTMLElement).offsetWidth`.

Comment: Oh, and you need to use the `nativeElement` after the init step of the life cycle hook. This means not in the constructor, but `ngOnInit` at least!

Comment: True that, when defined it before constructor it returned some error, so placed it into `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I'm getting "Can't bind to 'width' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg"

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Feel free to post a question with a [mcve]

Comment: If you get "Can't bind to 'width' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg" use: <svg:svg [attr.width]="container.offsetWidth"></svg:svg>

Comment: Try to use "container.el.offsetWidth" instead if container.offsetWidth is undefined.

Comment: Man... you did the trick easily and it worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone needs another solution:

```html
<div id="element"></div>
```

```typescript
const myElement = document.getElementById('element');

if(myElement){
  myElement.getBoundingClientRect().width; // Get the width of the your element
}
```