# How to restrict the div with a css badge when the content overflows

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I am having a scenario where the selected items are overflowing the div.
But I have managed to wrap it by css properties.

Now I am planning to put a css badge if the content width is crossing the parent div to transform from image 1 to image 2:

[image]

[image]
.

```
<div class="list-view">
    <div class="item-box">
        <h4>select Cities</h4>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of cityList" (click)="selectedCity(item)">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a sample code from this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uatw5p. 
I tried to achieve this but couldn't find a way. Can anyone let me know how to achieve this??

Comment: There's the CSS `overflow-wrap` rule ( or word-wrap )  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap that you can use to automatically wrap the text inside the div. And you can use the :after pseudo element to add the icon, so that you can position the icon relative to the div,. no matter how much overflowing or wrapping text there is inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice the list of array for the number of items you want to display. I used three items to display. And minus three from the total length of array. Use the CSS to format it the way you want.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  Cities
    <a *ngFor="let item of selectedItems.slice(0, 3)" href="javascript:void(0)">{{item}}</a>
   <div *ngIf="selectedItems.length > 3">+{{selectedItems.length - 3}}</div>
    <button (click)="selectedItems=[]">Reset</button>
</div>
```

The above will give you the following result:

[image]

**Edit:**
Use the following with the CSS provided in the another answer:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="selection">
   <p>Cities {{selectedItems.length? ' : ' + selectedItems.slice(0, 3): '' }}</p>
  <span *ngIf="selectedItems.length > 3">+{{selectedItems.length - 3}}</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I dont have problem in slicing the list. I have problem in restricting the content and placing that  +4 after selection

Comment: I guess I was not clear. I have updated my question please check once

Comment: Is there someway that I could check for max-width instead of *ngIf="selectedItems.length > 3"

Comment: Not sure about `max-width` but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708119/how-to-get-width-of-dom-element-in-angular-4-after-page-is-loaded?rq=1

Comment: You can easily check the max-width by binding it, use inline CSS, and bind.

Answer (score 1):

I would ellipsis the text to always allow space for the badge:

```
p {
    display:block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end of only ONE LINE!*/
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2; // experimental only! would allow ellipsis on 2nd line
    width: 370px; /* change to your preferences */
    white-space: nowrap; /* paragraph to one line */
    overflow:hidden; /* older browsers */
}
```

Comment: thanks pal. Your code is helped me to restrict with ellipses but do you have any idea how can I show a badge saying +2 more selected instead of hiding

Comment: Here it is but you'll have to add your requirements to it. Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-56562044

Answer (score 1):

It is the problem with text "Chennai,Mumbai,Pune,Bangalore" without spaces. If there is space, there would be on overflow of tex outside div

If you still require badge based on the text overflow, you need to add or remove css class based on parentDiv.offsetWidth and textDiv.offsetWidth. Css will dictate to show or hide the badge including ellipsis of text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following html for the anchor tag, manipulate the content by checking array length:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"> Cities {{selectedItems.length? (selectedItems.length < 3 ? ' : ' + selectedItems : ' : ' + selectedItems.slice(0,3) + '+' + (selectedItems.length-3) ): '' }}</a>
```

Output

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of overflow, overflow-wrap and white-space to make the text break correctly.

Then I would use a pseudo element to render the item count after the container.
By putting it absolute, we can align ther element relative to the container, no matter how many extra nodes we add to the container.

Since we use a pseudo-element, we can easily use the `content` css rule to bind the data-items attribute of the HTML container as the content of our little counter.

The big advantage is that by positioning the counter absolutely, we can keep using relative units to position everything else and we can put the counter anywhere we want, including putting overflow back on hidden and have the counter overlap the border.

```js
const cities = [
  "amsterdam",
  "belize",
  "calcutta",
  "dortmund",
  "egmond aan zee",
  "frankfurt",
  "gotenburg"
];

const render_list = list => content => {
  const items = content.map( text => `<li>${ text }</li>` ).join( '' );
  list.innerHTML = items;
  return list;
};

const add_city = list => event => {
  const item = event.target;
  if ( event.target.nodeName === 'LI' ) {
    list.appendChild( item.cloneNode(true));
    list.setAttribute( 'data-items', list.childElementCount );
  }
};

const options = document.querySelector( '#options' );
const selections = document.querySelector( '#selections' );

options.addEventListener( 'click', add_city( selections ));

render_list( options )( cities );
```

```css
#selections {
  background-color: steelblue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 4px;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-height: 1.1em;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
#selections:after {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  content: '+' attr(data-items);
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
}
#selections > li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
#options {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul data-items="0" id="selections"></ul>
<ul id="options"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, one simple css fix as `overflow-wrap: break-word;` by using word-break property

```
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background: skyblue;
  display: block;
  width: 20em;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 1.2em;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 16em;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image: op]