# How to get width of all elements of dropdown menu in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have this dropdown [image: menu] and I need to get the width of all items, compare it and get the biggest one. How we can do this in Angular ?

I tried with offsetWidth but I get only one width of this 4 elements and every time it's  changing .

```
      <div class="container">
                <div class="departments_link_container" [ngStyle]="{'width': megaMenuWidthContainer + 'px'}">
                    <a (click)="toggleActive(item, itemEl, i)" class="departments_link_item"
                       [routerLink]="itemEl.link | localize"
                       *ngFor="let itemEl of item.submenu">
                        <div class="icon" (click)="addActiveClass(itemEl, i)">
                            <img
                                [src]="itemEl?.icon?.path"
                                [transform]="['resize:fit:20:20', 'q:100']"
                                class="inactive"
                            />
                            <img
                                [src]="itemEl?.activeIcon?.path"
                                [transform]="['resize:fit:20:20', 'q:100']"
                                class="active"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <span id="megaMenuContainer" #megaMenuContainer (click)="addActiveClass(itemEl, i)" class="label"> {{ itemEl.title }}</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this, either directly in template or querying the elements. Not knowing why you need this I'm going to pick the latter option and query all the elements and then find the widest one of them. And I'm exactly not sure which item we're looking for so lets find the `<a>` tag elements, for example.

Let's add `#findElem` tag to we know we will query these elements.

```html
<a #findElem (click)="toggleActive(item, itemEl, i)" class="departments_link_item"
[routerLink]="itemEl.link | localize"
*ngFor="let itemEl of item.submenu">
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren('findElem') findElemList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.findElemList) {
      let widestElem;
      for (let item of this.findElemList) {
        if (!widestElem) {
          widestElem = item.nativeElement;
        } else if (widestElem.offsetWidth < item.nativeElement.offsetWidth) {
          widestElem = item.nativeElement;
        }
      }
      if (widestElem) {
        console.log('widest elem is: ', widestElem, ' width px is: ', widestElem.offsetWidth)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Feel free to refactor this here and there to find your elements.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vuk3h7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: <a #findElem (click)="toggleActive(item, itemEl, i)" class="departments_link_item"
[routerLink]="itemEl.link | localize"
*ngFor="let itemEl of item.submenu"> 
```
On ngAfterViewInit I get only first  item from NgFor but I need all items 
This Element Ref Return only first element from this list

Comment: That is not possible. `#findElem` is attached to each `<a>` elements the `*ngFor` generates. And `@ViewChildren` will query all such elements with `#findElem` tag. Only other option is, that `*ngFor` doesn't generate as many items as you think, or it does not do that on `AfterViewInit` cycle. That could happen if `item.submenu` is populated at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

this line of code show you the size of a div

```
<div #container>Container's width is {{ container.offsetWidth }}</div>
```

[as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708119/how-to-get-width-of-dom-element-in-angular-4-after-page-is-loaded)