# Angular - avoiding setTimeout() hack to get div width

Tags: angular, dom, event-handling, dom-events, angular-lifecycle-hooks

Wrote an Angular 13 component that draws something in a div whenever the window resizes.

The problem is getting the rendered width of the div. If I do not use setTimeout() with a 170ms delay, `this.treemap.nativeElement.offsetWidth` is zero.

As the treemap has to re-render each time the window resizes, I also tried dispatching a window resize event from ngAfterViewInit() but it also seems to happen too fast (so again, `this.treemap.nativeElement.offsetWidth` is zero).

Relevent part of the template...

```html
  <div #treemap class="treemap col-12"></div>
```

and abbreviated code...

```js
// Details omitted for brevity
export class TreemapComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('treemap') treemap!: ElementRef

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  private render() {
    const width = this.treemap.nativeElement.offsetWidth
    // code that successfully renders a treemap in the div as long as width != 0
  }

  callHack(): void {
    setTimeout(() => this.render(), 170) // testing shows 170ms is lowest possible
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.callHack()
    // window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')) // happens too fast (offsetWidth = 0)
  }
```

Is AfterViewInit the wrong lifecycle event hook ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845822/angular-2-get-width-of-a-div) suggested ngAfterViewInit)?

Is there a less-hacky approach to making this work in Angular 13?

Comment: There are couple of `hacks` (along with their explanation) mentioned in this post, see if any one works for your use case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947154/angular-2-viewchild-annotation-returns-undefined

Comment: What I wrote above works but it uses a hack (setTimeout). The examples on the other question are pretty much what I've already done to get it working. When I wrote the same component in Svelte, I didn't have to do any hacks because it uses the actual rather than a virtual DOM. It left me feeling like I'm missing some knowledge in Angular to make it work more elegantly.

Comment: Make an example on stackblitz with your problem.

Comment: @nstuyvesant I'm unable to get a zero width with just a regular div, could you please provide some way to reproduce this? What library are you using for the treemap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `ResizeObserver` to observe the element itself rather than the window.

```js
export class TreemapComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('treemap') treemap!: ElementRef;
  treemapObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => this.render());

  private render() {
    const width = this.treemap.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    // code that successfully renders a treemap in the div as long as width != 0
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.treemapObserver.observe(this.treemap.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.treemapObserver.unobserve(this.treemap.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

Credit to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39312522/12914833

Answer (score 0):

Try calling ngAfterViewChecked() instead of ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: First time ngAfterViewChecked() is triggered, the div width is zero so looks like that won't do it.